# Block as property and accessing Class instances variables

Tags: objective-c

I want to create a really dynamic class which has as property a block. 
What I want is to make this block function to be able to access Class instance variables and properties.

here the code with my doubt:

```
/* MyClass Interface */
@interface MyClass:NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *variable;
@property (nonatomic, assign) void (^updateFunction)();
@end


 /* MyClass implementation */
@implementation MyClass

-(void)update{ 
    //Perform the block function code
    self.updateFunction();
}
@end



/* MyClass usage*/
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc]init];
myClass.variable = @"Variable Value";
myClass.updateFunction = ^{ 
   //HERE MY DOUBT...
   //How can I access the myClass.variable and be sure that when this block
   //will be called it didn't get a bad access? 
}
```

So from the previous code my doubt is: **how to access instance variables for an Object directly from a block that has been stored as property of the Object itself.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your block function should have an argument to the instance:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) void (^updateFunction)(MyClass *obj);
```

Then call the block:

```
self.updateFunction(self);
```

So you can you:

```
myClass.variable = @"Variable Value";
myClass.updateFunction = ^(MyClass *obj) {
   NSLog(@"%@", obj.variable);
};
[myClass update];
```

Comment: I don't see why capturing `myClass` should not work. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: To allow the property declaration, you need to predefine the class before the @interface, with `@class MyClass`

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the instance `myClass` and its property `myClass.variable`
in the block without problems:

```
myClass.variable = @"Variable Value";
myClass.updateFunction = ^{
    NSLog(@"%@", myClass.variable);
};
[myClass update];
```

The block "captures" the value of the instance variable and also creates a strong
reference, so that the object is not deallocated.

But note that this creates a "retain cycle" so that `myClass` will never be deallocated.
So you must either release the block at some point to break the retain cycle:

```
myClass.updateFunction = nil;
```

or use a weak reference:

```
__weak MyClass *weakPtr = myClass;
myClass.updateFunction = ^{
    MyClass *strongPtr = weakPtr;
    if (strongPtr) {
        NSLog(@"%@", strongPtr.variable);
    }
};
```

In the second case, `myClass` might get deallocated, but then the captured `weakPtr`
is automatically set to `nil` by the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: [MyClass update] is called in a totally different scope.Sorry, I try to improve my question with more details.

Comment: @MatterGoal: My answer works also if `[myClass update]` is called from somewhere else. If your intention is that the block should be called with "its own class pointer" then this just works, and passing `self` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your block function could call a (private) method in the class from which the property values are used.